# representing topics and tables in one table vs. two tables?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently building a forum component for a larger application and I'm considering different approaches to certain parts of the database schema. In particular, I am considering representing topics and posts in a single table. While I view topics and posts as practically the same, I feel a bit apprehensive as this may make things less flexible in the future.

When topics of a particular forum are queried, the title and first post will be shown as well as some of the user information (basically the name and avatar). In this application, there are various attributes that are used by both topics and posts except for views and replies; and perhaps title, and forum_id(forum_id because that would mean potentially hundreds of records need to be affected if a topic is changed to another forum as opposed to changing the forum_id attribute in the topic relation).

The tables look something like what I have below here:

```
TOPIC            POST           
topic_id         poster_id   
forum_id         topic_id 
poster_id        content 
title            upvote
views            dnvote
replies          closed
post_id          deleted
                 last_edited
                 last_editor
                 parent_id
                 content
                 post_id
```

Doing it this way, using table inheritance, generating the posts in the topic would require a 4-table join via TOPIC, POST, USER, and TOPIC_TYPE.

On the other hand, if I decide to take the single table approach, should I simply leave the views, replies, title, and forum_id attributes as null if the topic_type is a regular post? (topic_type references an appropriate icon for the type of topic displayed, and will be used for statistics and etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are definitely committed to using relational technology (I would consider NoSQL db for this like Mongo, etc. as well) I would separate into two tables as you proposed.

Your case here is a fundamental of relational master-detail design or whole-parts and I think that two tables are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this scenario simple normalization is preferred. It will also be useful to generate different types of reports as well. Although single table may be used but as you have designed the table in this case if you use two tables that would be more manageable to avoid entry of same value multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to distinguish between a "topic" and a "topic starter" as such.  A "topic starter" is a comment that is not a reply.  Every topic has exactly one topic starter, which could be referenced by a foreign key in the topic table.

Other than that, I agree with both your analysis and your design.